# Validate new AD password according to local security policy?

Tags: c#, regex, security, sharepoint, active-directory

I would like to allow the current user to change their password (managed via active directory).

I would like to validate and then set their password in Active Directory (currently using the [SetPassword invoke method](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#46)).

My problem is validating the password so that it meets the complexity requirements:

> Not contain the user's account name or
>   parts of the user's full name that
>   exceed two consecutive characters Be
>   at least six characters in length
>   Contain characters from three of the
>   following four categories: English
>   uppercase characters (A through Z)
>   English lowercase characters (a
>   through z) Base 10 digits (0 through
>   9) Non-alphabetic characters (for
>   example, !, $, #, %) Complexity
>   requirements are enforced when
>   passwords are changed or created.

I'm already using a `CompareValidator` with two textboxes so I was thinking about adding a `RegularExpressionValidator` ([source 1](http://www.webpronews.com/expertarticles/2006/12/14/validating-strong-passwords-in-c-and-aspnet), [source 2](http://en.csharp-online.net/ASP.NET_Security_Hacks%E2%80%94Validating_a_Strong_Password_in_Login_Controls)) but I'm not sure how to get it to work with the whole "three of four categories" thing:

```
RegularExpressionValidator revComplex = new RegularExpressionValidator();
revComplex.ControlToValidate = _txtPassword1.ID;
revComplex.ErrorMessage = "Password must have at least 7 characters. Characters should be from at least three of the following four groups: uppercase letter, lowercase letter, digit, or special characters  (for example, !, $, #, %).";
revComplex.ValidationExpression = @"^(?=.{7,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*s).*$";
```

Surely someone has tried to do this before? How should I validate a user's password before sending it to Active Directory according to the local security policy?

Comment: This is a bad candidate for regular expressions.

Comment: Found someone trying to do a very similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992474/determine-ad-password-policy-programmatically

@John: Agreed, which is why I thought I should ask this question. Maybe a CustomValidator?

Comment: Yeah, a custom validator is almost certainly your best bet here.  I do, however, agree with Tom's answer below, since it is more resilient to changing policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho, you can better use ChangePassword than SetPassword. That way, you require the user to specify his current (old) password. That may be interesting, because you can never be 100% sure that the user who is browsing your site is actually the user who is logged in.

Here's a link with more information:
http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article66.aspx

You do not have to validate the password in advance. Just send it to AD in a try-catch, and if it's not validated, the reason why will be in the exception message.

Comment: I'm +1 here, even though this is a bit of a non-answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will probably switch to use ChangePassword. As for just catching the exception... I'm still testing (trying to overcome a weird ACCESS DENIED issue), but I'm not sure about how detailed the exception is. I would prefer to give the user more specific feedback as to why their new password is bad.

Comment: After more research, it seems impossible to perform a reliable check without sending it to AD. This question had some helpful links as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225168/how-can-you-test-if-an-ad-password-will-meet-configured-complexity-requirements

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to diagnose the error in a bit more detail. It does not provided any feedback from AD, but we can perhaps create a mapping  of the COM errors to a user friendly message.

This article provides more information about handling the possible COM errors:

http://www.ozkary.com/2015/03/active-directory-setpassword-or.html

I think more detail can be added for these COM errors:

0x800708c5 
0x8007202f 
0x8007052d
0x8007052f